# How to know who is active or not active on app?

Tags: java, android

I'm using OnStart and OnPause method for detecting when the user is active or not active. And then I send the data to the server. But when the user lose its internet connection while active on the activity and then closes the app. Then it can't send the data to the server. So how can I deal with this type of situations.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
       //User Is Active
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        //User Is Inactive
    }
```

Comment: You can create a temp file or using sqlite to stored this status when user offline. Then when user online, you will synchonize the local data to your server.

Comment: It's actually a chat app. If the user lose its internet. Then it will show the user as active to other until the internet comes back...

Comment: I think that in your app you need to send a request to a server app to let it know the client is online every minute. In server app, if after 1 minute without client status update then change the status to offline

Comment: you should use firebase

Comment: Does firebase have any function for that? @EliasFazel

Comment: ANd thanx @TuyenNguyenI'll try that